# Multiple aliases based on taxonomy terms

Tags: 7, path-aliases

I have a content type which has a categories field that contains values from A-C. This is a multi-select list as below.

[image]

I have configured the URL pattern as below.

```
categories/[node:field-token-of-term-reference-field]/[node:title]
```

As long as I select a single value from the list, the URL looks alright. **example.com/categories/a/planning**

The issue is when I need to assign multiple categories for a given node. Then the URL becomes **example.com/categories/a-b/planning** instead of one alias for **example.com/categories/a/planning** and another for **example.com/categories/b/planning**

My search engine doesn't like all categories in one URL and the preferred method is to have a URL per category. Is this even possible from Drupal?

Comment: You would end up having several URLs (aliases) to the same content. Are you sure this is not even worse for your search engine? By the way, if this is possible to disclose, which is your search engine? One URL per category would be a standard way when that URL ends in the category itself, and then the page shows the list of items under such category, I guess.

Comment: The search engine I'm using is zoom search. The search engine provides the category search feature where we can give the patterns. I will not be duplicating content, just the aliases. Say I have 'planning' article linked to Category A and B. When someone do a search for planning but just within category B, I need the results to show up.